# access the $routeparam and $stateParam objects with the dot

Tags: angularjs, routes

I taking me too much to debuge this thing i can't seem to figure this out.I think am missing some basic here. here is my problem consol.log($stateParams) returns the params out in the console like this

> energyChain: "6"energyId: "1"facilityId: "1"resourceId: "1"
>   but when running like this to get specific params

consol.log($stateParams.energyChain) returns

```
undfined
6
```

for this link http://localhost:3238/#/resource/1/6/1/1 
here either the controller is excuted two times one time undefined value one time 6 value which is true or statesparam is returning the old value to my variable

here is my code

```
                    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid', "ngAnimate", "ngAria", 'ngMaterial', "ui.router"]);
                myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

                    // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
                    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")

                    $stateProvider
                      .state('firstState', {
                          url: "/resource/:energyId/:energyChain/:resourceId/:facilityId",
                          templateUrl: "/Content/resourceTemplate.html",
                          controller: "detailsController"
                      })

                });

                myApp.controller('detailsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
                    console.log($stateParams.energyChain);

                    $scope.models = [
                             { Parameter: "Power", Values: "23", Per: "Of Mega watt", Scale: "Hundred", Unit: "MW", Period: "October" },
                             { Parameter: "Power", Values: "23", Per: "Of Mega watt", Scale: "Hundred", Unit: "MW", Period: "September" },
                             { Parameter: "Power", Values: "23", Per: "Of Mega watt", Scale: "Hundred", Unit: "MW", Period: "October" },
                             { Parameter: "Power", Values: "23", Per: "Of Mega watt", Scale: "Hundred", Unit: "MW", Period: "Annual" },
                             { Parameter: "Power", Values: "23", Per: "Of Mega watt", Scale: "Hundred", Unit: "MW", Period: "Annual" },
                             { Parameter: "Power", Values: "23", Per: "Of Mega watt", Scale: "Hundred", Unit: "MW", Period: "Annual" },
                             { Parameter: "Power", Values: "23", Per: "Of Mega watt", Scale: "Hundred", Unit: "MW", Period: "Annual" }
                    ];


                    $scope.years = ['2015', '2014', '2013', '2012', '2011', '2010'];
                    $scope.Annuals = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                                    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

                }]);
```

but cant access the params individually due to this error

Comment: You have $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/") in your code. Where is the state associated with url / ?

Comment: 1) link you gave is for the localhost, it opens only in your server
2) can you provide a fiddle or plunker? or provide more code

Comment: console.log($routeParams);
    //this returns two values consquetively undefined and pram value so how can i get to return the current value only